# Tags speech and spoken-language

Tags: discussion, tags

The two tags [speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) and [spoken-language](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language) are currently without a tag wiki. However, they are are very overlapping and I cannot find a good delineation between the two. Some posts in speech (and in [speed](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed)) deal with speach-rate specifically, maybe speech-rate is a good new tag.

Any proposals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, [speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) and [spoken-language](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language) seem to have a good degree of overlap. One option is to merge the two tags.

I am not too keen creating tag wikis for [speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) or [speech-rate](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-rate), quite the contrary, I'd prefer these tags deleted. This is my rationale: rather than think of these tags as part of an ontology of sorts, I prefer to think of them in terms of their utility to the users of Linguistics Stackexchange site.

As far as I know, there are two ways of using tags:

1. Click on the tag to find all the questions tagged as such.
2. Adding one or more tags to free-form words in the search field.

For either of these options, the existence of [speech-rate](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-rate) seems pointless.

1. There are just two questions with [speed](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed), indicating that this is not a topic in popular demand. IMO, if a tag is populated by extremely few questions, there is little reason for it to exist in the long term. New questions may be tagged with all kinds of new terms, but if after a couple of years, there are no more questions with that tag, the tag should be deleted. Just my 2¢.
2. When looking for questions on *speech rate*, users can add these words to the query even if the tags did not exist.

Comment: I agree with merging the two tags, which one should be the result of the merger? Thinking in terms of modality I'd prefer [tag:spoken-language] (in analogy with [tag:written-language])

Comment: @jknappen Done.